# How to fix npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.4 npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@12.2.2?

Tags: angular, npm

I am trying to update angular cli version locally, however everytime I run the following command I keep getting the following error:

npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli. (trying to follow steps shown [here](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/update-angular-cli-version-ng-update-to-latest-6-7-versions/))

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.4
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@12.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~12.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@15.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

If I try to run command: npm install, I get the following too:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.4
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@12.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~12.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@15.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

Whatever I try I get the same error message and I have not found anything of value online. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following commands

npm install --force

ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15 --force

Also enter this command so you wont have to use --force again. This should resolve the dependency conflicts

npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

Comment: Hi, this works, the only thing is that I first had to run this command ng update @angular/core@VERSION @angular/cli@VERSION --force.  for version 13, then 14 and finally 15. It worked.   VERSION refers to version number.

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 options:

Satisfy the @angular-devkit/build-angular peer dependency requirement FIRST by installing

```
npm i @angular/compiler-cli@^15.0.0
```

then run your command again

Or let npm resolve it using legacy peer deps resolution:

```
npm uninstall -D angular-cli --legacy-peer-deps
```