# Unable to install @angular/material with angular 17

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm doing `ng add @angular/material` to my project.  it fails with ...

```
The package @angular/material@17.0.4 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@17.1.0-next.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^17.1.0-next.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/animations@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @angular/material@17.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!   @angular/material@"17.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

what do I need to do?

Comment: Looks like you have the pre-releases in the your `package.json`. The final `17.1.0` will be released mid january.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using the @next version of @angular/animations? Perhaps due to the SSR packages?

It is advisable to keep all @angular packages at the same version, for example 17.0 or lower, since 17.1 is not out yet.

It is hard to say with certainty without seeing your package.json file, but I would downgrade the pre-release versions to the latest stable versions 17.0.x and then update @angular/material. Ideally not with "forcing it", or with depending on legacy configurations, that's not necessary and you're using very recent versions of Angular. It's essentially a matter of getting your packages on the same major version.

If this cannot be done automatically through the schematics or your installer, you can do the following.

- Commit a stable version to your repo, or backup your files
- Manually change the package.json so it matches 17. For example, mine is "@angular/animations": "^17.0.8".
- Run "npm install", if that doesn't work, remove package-lock.json, or even the node-modules/ folder and try again.

Again, make sure you backup whatever stable version you have working first.

One package that's very userful, if you're using is NPM-GUI, you can run it with:

```
npx npm-gui@latest
```

And you'll have a GUI in the browser to perform upgrades and downgrades.

Comment: check out this post for a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75011834/how-to-fix-npm-err-while-resolving-angular-devkit-build-angular15-0-4-npm-er/75012104#75012104